# Adding column to df and create conditional series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `'df'` with one column named 'Value'  that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255]})

Value
240
241
242
243
244
245
246
247
248
249
250
251
252
253
254
255
```

What I would like to do is to add a second column 'NewValue' so that I get a column like this:

```
Value NewValue
240   7
241   8
242   9
243   10
244   11
245   12
246   13
247   14
248   15
249   0
250   1
251   2
252   3
253   4
254   5
255   6
```

The second column should contain an ascending series from 0 to 15 where the variable `zerovalue` defines the (index) place of the value 0. In the example above `zerovalue = 249`.
I know that I could add a new column and change the row value based on the rowIndex like this:

```
rowIndex = df.index[9]
df.loc[rowIndex, 'NewValue'] = 0
```

How could I add this second column that contains the series like in the example above and that `zerovalue` which defines the place of the zero column is changeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I an using `cumsum` with `agrsort` , then assign the value by `index`

```
s=df.Value.eq(249).cumsum()
df.loc[s.iloc[(-s).argsort()].index,'NewValue']=np.arange(len(df))
df
Out[134]: 
    Value  NewValue
0     240         7
1     241         8
2     242         9
3     243        10
4     244        11
5     245        12
6     246        13
7     247        14
8     248        15
9     249         0
10    250         1
11    251         2
12    252         3
13    253         4
14    254         5
15    255         6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `np.roll`, first calcuate the shift position using boolean condition and `sum`:

```
shift = (df['Value'] < 249).sum()
df['NewValue'] = np.roll(np.arange(len(df)), shift)
```

Output:

```
    Value  NewValue
0     240         7
1     241         8
2     242         9
3     243        10
4     244        11
5     245        12
6     246        13
7     247        14
8     248        15
9     249         0
10    250         1
11    251         2
12    252         3
13    253         4
14    254         5
15    255         6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
df['NewValue'] = np.arange(0, len(df.Value))
df['NewValue'].shift(np.argwhere(df.Value== zerovalue)[0][0]).fillna(0) + df['NewValue'].shift(np.argwhere(df.Value== zerovalue)[0][0] - len(df.Value)).fillna(0)
```

It first creates a column from range 0 to length, then pushes it down by zerovalue's index and again creates another column which pulls up overflowed numbers and merges them.